# How to exclude password protect for a url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection

The site has two urls.

http://example.com

http://example1.com

Password protect is added via .htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "You must give a password"
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Now password protection is applied for both the urls. How to exclude password protection for http://example1.com.

Comment: A lot of guessing going on, since the question is not clear.  Your using apache web server, and servering the exact same site from two domains?  Is that the setup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For which version of Apache? (Apache 2.4 has some new features)

```
SetEnvIf Host ^example1\.com$ bypass=1

Satisfy any

Order allow,deny
Allow from env=bypass

AuthUserFile ...
AuthName ...
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

?

Comment: Thanks julp. I am using apache2. This solution is working.